# Shrink tensorflow binary size on iOS

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I've successfully built the camera demo from the ios_example and it's running perfect. The problem is that the binary size is comparatively large (Around 11MB binary footprint per CPU architecture).  What i'm trying to do now is to shrink the binary size as much as possible.

There is a part named '*Reducing the binary size*' in the official document: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples   .  In the last paragraph it said:

> After that, you can manually look at modifying the list of kernels included in tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt to reduce the number of implementations to the ones you're actually using in your own model.

So i removed a bunch of items from tf_op_files.txt and rebuilt iOS binary by executing compile_ios_tensorflow.sh, hoping it would reduce the generated binary size. However, the size didn't change at all, not even a single bit. I've tried serval times, i also tried to clear all the content of tf_op_files.txt, but still got the same result.

I guess i was doing wrong somewhere. Does anyone know how to do it right? Or is there any other way to reduce the binary size except those from the official  documentation?

Any information is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TF already has to [tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/quantization/quantize_graph.py) to do [8-bit Quantize](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization). It can largely decrease the model size but may hurt the precision.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not trying to shrink the model file (graph.pb). I've already done that. What i'm asking is how to shrink the binary file (libtensorflow-core.a). Thanks anyway!